# cloudbees & ESAPI - how do I point to the ESAPI directory?

Tags: java, resources, directory, cloudbees, esapi

I'm using ESAPI for my project, and added the ESAPI configuration directory to `src/main/resources` so it is copied to my WAR file (I downloaded the WAR from cloudbees, I can see it was put in `WEB-INF/classes/esapi/` directory)

Locally, I just point to where the directory is and all works fine, but on cloudbees it just doesn't work for me.

In order to access its properties, ESAPI project tries all kinds of stuff, including checking the `org.owasp.esapi.resources` system property, so I've added the following code to `cloudbees-web.xml`:

```
<sysprop name="org.owasp.esapi.resources" value="WEB-INF/classes/esapi/" />
```

and I can see that the system property **value** is found because of the following error in the logs:

```
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /var/genapp/apps/akld3873/WEB-INF/classes/esapi/ESAPI.properties
```

so it finds the system property (because the path is like I've specified), but when it looks for the actual directory and files in it, I guess the directory is either not there or not readable.

Do I need to move it somewhere else?  Inside the WEB-INF directory maybe? Is the setting not right?  I've read that others solved similar issues by building a JAR just for this directory, but this doesn't seem like a good solution, there must be a simple setup that will work for cloudbees.

Comment: I also tried: /tip-about/WEB-INF/esapi/ESAPI.properties but got again : Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: /var/genapp/apps/1xxx7/tip-about/WEB-INF/esapi/ESAPI.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after searching and testing, I finally figured it out.
Cloudbees deploys your web app to the following directory:

```
staxcat/install/webapp.war/
```

notice that this is a relative path, with prefix of this path attached it looks something like this:

```
/var/genapp/apps/xxxxxxxx/staxcat/install/webapp.war/WEB-INF/esapi/ESAPI.properties
```

so, in order to get ESAPI to work, I had to set the following in cloudbees-web.xml:

```
<sysprop name="org.owasp.esapi.resources" value="staxcat/install/webapp.war/WEB-INF/esapi" />
```

this will enable ESAPI to find the directory if in your project it is located under:

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/esapi
```

and you should get the following log line:

```
Found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory: /var/genapp/apps/xxxxxxxxx/staxcat/install/webapp.war/WEB-INF/esapi/ESAPI.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Design for ESAPI lib to require a directory access to configuration is not very flexible.
A general purpose option is to use [ServletContext.getRealPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29) to resolve the absolute filesystem path to this directory and pass it to ESAPI.

Another option is for you to have some init code to copy WEB-INF/classes/esapi content in a temporary directory (using java.io.temp system property to point to the currently configured temp dir for your app) and point ESAPI lib to this path.

Comment: I agree that this requirement is not flexible, but I'll have to live with it for now.  Thanks for your suggestions, I will take a look and try to implement one.

Comment: @nicolas de loof ESAPI doesn't require it, the actual intent for using the library is that you'll copy the source repo and build it yourself, putting the properties files unique to your library where Maven expects it.  When they're included in the ESAPI jarFile's classpath, directory access is unnecessary.